# Strip type Pdf generating using reportlab in django

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

I want to create a strip type pdf in django using Reportlab. The output pdf should be in 79mm width and its height should be content height (endless). Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show some of the research you already did or code that you tried, this way the community can help you solve the issues you run into. You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I create pdf according to reportlab tutorial and it works for me in A4 page size. But I don't know how I setup a  page size that I mention above. Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick reminder, If an answer solved you problem please accept that answer by clicking the green check mark below the vote counter.

Answer (score 0):

The way the pagesize is set depends on whether you use PLATYPUS or just canvases. First to make sure that you get the proper height use `pageWidth = 79 * mm` (this requires `from reportlab.lib.units import mm`. The `pageHeight` is something you have to specify your self.

From there you can set the size based on the object used, in the case you use Platypus is done as follows:

```
baseDocTemplate(self, filename, pagesize=(pageWidth, pageHeight))
```

If you use a canvas is done like this:

```
canvas.setPageSize((pageWidth, pageHeight))
```

Reportlab also contains default pagesizes which are also pair like mentioned above they can be found in `from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4`